# Reflection - Invoke method with Long and Number args

Tags: java, methods, reflection

I have the following method in a class called NumberToStringConverter:

```
public String convert(Number input) {
  return String.valueOf(input);
}
```

I want to invoke the method with the following code:

```
NumberToStringConverter obj = new NumberToStringConverter();
Method m = obj.getClass().getMethod("convert", new Class[] { Long.class });
m.invoke(obj, new Object[] { aLongObject });
```

The thing is, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: NumberToStringConverter.convert(java.lang.Long)
```

When you write your own code, Java allows invoking a method that has a Number argument with a Long argument. It automatically converts the Long into a Number object. Why doesn't this match happen with reflection? And how can I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change your method like this:

```
public String convert(Long input) {
  return String.valueOf(input);
}
```

Or change the calling to the method:

```
Method m = obj.getClass().getMethod("convert", new Class[] { Number.class });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should match your method signature (parameter type).

Change

```
Method m = obj.getClass().getMethod("convert", new Class[] { Long.class });
```

to

```
Method m = obj.getClass().getMethod("convert", new Class[] { Number.class });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Number.class

```
NumberToStringConverter obj = new NumberToStringConverter();
Method m = obj.getClass().getMethod("convert", new Class[] { Number.class });
m.invoke(obj, new Object[] { aLongObject });
```